# Using Python, NLTK, to analyse German text

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, corpus

I am a beginner in Python and currently trying to use NLTK to analyze German text (extract the German noun and it's frequency of German text) by following this tutorial: https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2016/07/13/accurate-part-of-speech-tagging-of-german-texts-with-nltk/

There are several issues that I faced during the process and I am not able to solve them.

When I follow the website to execute the code below:

```
import random

tagged_sents = list(corp.tagged_sents())
random.shuffle(tagged_sents)
split_perc = 0.1
split_size = int(len(tagged_sents) * split_perc)
train_sents, test_sents = tagged_sents[split_size:], tagged_sents[:split_size]
```

and it comes out with this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    tagged_sents = list(corp.tagged_sents())
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\conll.py", line 130, in tagged_sents
    return LazyMap(get_tagged_words, self._grids(fileids))
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\conll.py", line 215, in _grids
    return concat(
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py", line 433, in concat
    raise ValueError("concat() expects at least one object!")
ValueError: concat() expects at least one object!
```

Then I try to fix by following this solution https://teamtreehouse.com/community/randomshuffle-crashes-when-passed-a-range-somenums-randomshufflerange5250

and alter the
`tagged_sents = list(corp.tagged_sents())`

to
`tagged_sents = list(range(5,250))`

And the ValueError didn't come out, I don't know what (5,250) means, although I have read the explanation.

Then I continue to execute the follow step

```
from ClassifierBasedGermanTagger.ClassifierBasedGermanTagger import ClassifierBasedGermanTagger
tagger = ClassifierBasedGermanTagger(train=train_sents)
```

And it shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 90, in <module>
    from ClassifierBasedGermanTagger.ClassifierBasedGermanTagger import ClassifierBasedGermanTagger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ClassifierBasedGermanTagger'
```

I have already downloaded the ClassifierBasedGermanTagger.py and **init**.py and put them in the folder which link to the VS CODE, don't know if it is correct as the passage said:

'Using his Python class ClassifierBasedGermanTagger (which you can download from the github page) we can create a tagger and train it with the data from the TIGER corpus:'

Please help me to fix these problems, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow! Before posting a question, please make sure that you have done your own research and most of the time it solves the problem.

Secondly, `range(start, end)` is a very basic function in Python to get list of numbers based on the input and I don't think using it like the way you did is going to solve the problem. I would suggest you to use `print` to see what kind of data is being populated in `corp` and start debugging from there. Maybe `corp` is just empty and that's why you don't get any `tagged_sents`.

For the the import part, it is not clear to me where did you put the `ClassifierBasedGermanTagger.py` but wherever it is, it is not visible to your code. You can try to put your code (`test2.py`) and `ClassifierBasedGermanTagger.py` in the same directory. Read the link below for more details on how to properly import module in Python.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html